# Prove that when x approaches to 1-, the function appraochs to negative infinity

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Prove that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}f(x):=\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}\frac{x+2}{2x^2-3x+1}=-\infty.$$
Using the basic definition.

This is the proof from the textbook:

Let $M\in R$ and assume M<0 without losing generality. As x converges to 1 from the left-hand side, $2x^2-3x+1$ is negative and approaches to 0 as x approaches to 1.

By observing that x has roots 1/2 and 1 and is a parabola opening upward, choosing $\delta\in(0,1)$ such that $1-\delta<x<1$ implies $2/M<2x^2-3x+1<0$;

That is, $-1/(2x^2-3x+1)>-M/2>0$. Since $0<x<1$ also implies $2<x+2<3$, it follows that $-(x+2)/(2x^2-3x+1)>-M$ ; that is,
$$f(x)=\frac{x+2}{2x^2-3x+1}<M$$
for all $1-\delta<x<1$.

I can follow the proof step by step but I have no idea why this question is proved in this way, the "choosing $\delta\in(0,1) $ such that... implies $2/M<2x^2-3x+1<0$" seems jump from no where. Could someone please tell me what's the reasoning behind each step? That is how poeople come up with the idea to solve the problem this way?

Comment: In terms of how they come up with it, first they conjecture what the limit is (test some values, or simply by understanding the function). Then, they take $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of the function around the conjectured limit to see how tightly they can bound inputs. Then after some cleaning up, you get this.

Answer (score 1):

I like to let variables
go to zero.

So, in
$\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}\frac{x+2}{2x^2-3x+1}
$
I would let
$x = 1-y$.

Then
$x+2 = 1-y+2
=3-y$
and

$\begin{array}\\
2x^2-3x+1
&=2(1-y)^2-3(1-y)+1\\
&=2(1-2y+y^2)-3+3y+1\\
&=2-4y+2y^2-3+3y+1\\
&=-y+2y^2\\
&=y(-1+2y)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\lim_{x\rightarrow1-}\frac{x+2}{2x^2-3x+1}
=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{3-y}{y(-1+2y)}
$
and it is easy to see why this diverges.

Note that
$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{3-y}{-1+2y}
=-3
$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow... why is it easy to see this diverges?

Comment: Because all the other terms ($3-y$ and $-1+2y$) approach nonzero limits as $y \to 0$, so all that is left is the $y$ in the denominator, so the fraction diverges as $\frac{-3}{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

$2x^{2}-3x+1=(2x-1)(x-1)<0$ for $1/2<x<1$. So with $\delta\in(0,1/2)$ then $1-\delta>1-1/2=1/2$, so with $1-\delta<x<1$, then $1/2<x<1$, with such $\delta\in(0,1)$, at least we can conclude that $2x^{2}-3x+1<0$.

Now it remains to pick a $\delta\in(0,1/2)$ small enough to get $2x^{2}-3x+1>2/M$. If you use the cheating argument that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}(2x^{2}-3x+1)=0$, then you may choose a $\delta'>0$ (need no to be $\delta'\in(0,1/2)$ at first) such that $1-\delta'<x<1$, $|2x^{2}-3x+1|<-2/M$ (keep in mind that $M<0$ so $-2/M>0$), this is merely from the definition of left limit. As a result, $2x^{2}-3x+1>-(-2/M)=2/M$ by the usual triangle inequality.

So now we take $\delta_{0}=\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$, this $\delta_{0}$ satisfies $\delta_{0}\in(0,1/2)$ so we have again $2x^{2}-3x+1<0$. On the other hand, for $1-\delta_{0}<x<1$, then $1-\delta'<x<1$ and hence $2x^{2}-3x+1>2/M$.

Comment: But I believe 0<c<2 is based on choosing $\delta\in (0,1)$, right? So in order to cancel out 2 from M/2, I have to choose $\delta\in (0,1)$

Comment: Why all of a sudden there is a $c$?

Comment: sorry typo... I meant x, the third paragraph of the proof "since $0<x<1$ also implies $2<x+2<3$".

Comment: The reasoning about that should be rephrased as the following order: If $x$ is such that $1-\delta<x<1$, as $\delta\in(0,1)$, then $0<x<2$, this implies $2<x+2<3$...

Comment: You choose $\delta\in(0,1)$ to make that $-2/M<2x^{2}-3x+1<0$ works, and for this $\delta>0$ and any $x$ such that $1-\delta<x<1$, then $2<x+2<3$ and the rest of algebras follow.

Comment: Yea but if I choose $\delta\in(0,1/2)$ I wouldn't be able to get $2<x+2$ and wouldn't be able to cancel 2 out from the 2/M, does that mean if I replace 2 with 5/2, and use $\delta\in(0,1/2)$ to complete the proof?

Comment: If $\delta\in(0,1/2)$, then $1-\delta>1-1/2=1/2>0$, it is still true that if $1-\delta<x$, then $x>0$ and hence $x+2>2$.